# How to make images compatible with Retina Display (iPad) Rails App?

Tags: iphone, ipad

**I am currently using Paperclip and AmazonS3 to upload images to my Rails App.**

Everything works perfectly on my desktop and the images look great, But for some reason when I use my iPhone or an iPad....the images get pixelated.

**Does anyone know why this happens and what I need to add to my Rails App in order to make it compatible with IOS Devices.**

New to Rails....Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like http://retinajs.com

Comment: @Stefan would this mean that for every Image I upload...their has to be a higher resolution copy somewhere in my server(and how much higher). Wouldn't that become a problem if I am running a high image driven application. Or would changing the name to 2x simply change the resolution of a picture.....and what happens to all the pictures already in the database. Would i need to reupload everything?

Comment: You need twice the resolution (2x). Take a look at apple.com, there's http://images.apple.com/home/images/ios_hero_short.png and http://images.apple.com/home/images/ios_hero_short_2x.png